# In Java, why is assert a keyword and not a method?

Tags: java, methods, assert

Why is `assert` in java a keyword, and not a method?

The method assert could look like this:

```
public static void assert(boolean condition) {
    if(!condition) {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this question is available in [The Java® Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10)

> An assertion is an assert statement containing a boolean expression. An assertion is either enabled or disabled. If the assertion is enabled, execution of the assertion causes evaluation of the boolean expression and an error is reported if the expression evaluates to false. If the assertion is disabled, execution of the assertion has no effect whatsoever.

So, if `assert` were a method then such code:

```
assert(check());
```

will **always** call the `check` method, **regardless** whether the assertion is enabled or disabled.

Now, since `assert` is a keyword with a special handling (as described above) the `check` method will be called **only** when the assertion is enabled as only then the boolean expression of this assert will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Java assertions can be turned on and off without changes to the code.  This makes it possible to avoid the runtime overhead of assertions in production, while taking advantage of their debugging value in development environments.

Assertions implemented as method calls in application code would not perform as well.  Even if the method can be short-circuited or not as desired for each environment, cycles are always burned by the method call and the test to determine if it is active or not.

In practice, the Java assert keyword is not popular, at least not at this juncture.  Assertions are far more often implemented in JUnit tests, as other posters have touched upon.  In the JUnit world, assertions *are* method calls.  They impose no overhead in production because they are not in the mainline code; they are in separate test code that is only run in development environments.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that assertions can be enabled or disabled - this is better modelled in Java (a language with no preprocessor) with a keyword rather than a method, since the assumption with a method is that the code would always run (even though it would be possible to make the compiler remove the method calls if assertions were disabled).

Contrast this to assertions in e.g. C or C++, where you have a preprocessor - in that case, it suffices to preprocess out the assertions based on whether or not a particular preprocessor flag is defined.